# Find the number where the path of two numbers in a binary tree overlap

Tags: binary-tree

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int binTree(int n, int m){
    if(n == m)
        return m;
    else if(n < m)
        return binTree(n, m/2);
    else if(n > m)
        return binTree(n/2, m);
}


int main(){
    int n,m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << binTree(n, m);
}
```

However the compiler tells me that "Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths" in my binTree function... I don't see how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, I understand your point.  The compiler is likely determining that you are not closing out with a default `else` consider removing the initial condition and allowing that to resolve as your default state.

```
if (n < m)
    return binTree(n, m/2);
else if (n > m)
    return binTree(n/2, m);
return m
```